# jquery checkall not effecting checked elements

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a few check boxes that add a class "filtered" to an LI with specific data attribute (which both the LI and the checkbox have) when unchecked to hide the unchecked sources/categories.  I've added a checkall button above, and it works to set all the checkboxes to checked, however, it has no impact on the elements that were hidden when I checked/unchecked the boxes directly.  Is it possible to bind the display of 1 div to the value of the checkboxes in another?

for instance, on loading the page, check if the checkbox with the same data-category is checked and then display the content? perhaps I should do that with php?

checkbox code for adding/removing class filtered onclick:

```
$("#side_categories #sourcestoggle ul#side_categories_prog li .check_box input").click(function () {
    var dealcat = $(this).data('dealcat'); //get the category from the clicked button
    var deallistcount = $('#deals .deal:visible').size();
    if (deallistcount < 0) {
        $('#deals .noresults').show();
    } else {
        $('#deals .noresults').hide();
    }
    if ($('#' +dealcat+ ':checked').val() !==undefined) {
        $('#deals .deal[data-dealcat*="' +dealcat+ '"]').removeClass('filtered');
        $('#dealcount .counter #showingval').html(parseInt($('#deals .deal:visible').size()));
    } else {
        $('#deals .deal[data-dealcat*="' +dealcat+ '"]').addClass('filtered');
        $('#dealcount .counter #showingval').html(parseInt($('#deals .deal:visible').size()));
        var deallistcount = $('#deals .deal:visible').size();
        if (deallistcount < 1) {
            $('#deals .noresults').show();
        } else {
            $('#deals .noresults').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

my code for the checkall:

```
$('#side_categories #sourcestoggle .sources #sources_controls .sources_checkall').click(function(){
    $('#side_categories #sourcestoggle ul#side_categories_prog li .check_box input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

I understand that with the checkall/uncheckall the easiest way would be to just remove all class filtered from #deals, and vice versus, but i'm trying to see if there is a "smarter" way of doing it.

html of the listings ul/li:

```
  <ul id="deals">
    <li data-date="26800" data-discount="50" data-value="400" data-price="200" id="9752" data-dealcat="Provider" data-category="Category" class="deal">
      blah blah blah
    </li>
  </ul>
```

categories/checkbox html:

```
  <ul id='side_categories_prog'>
  <li class='programname'>
  <div class='check_box'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2' name='sources1' id='programname' checked='checked' data-dealcat='programname'>
  </div>
  <label for='progname'>programname</label>";
  </li>
  </ul>
```

The data for the checkboxes is filled in with php and via jquery it controls #deals .deal which are also dynamically filled in.

Comment: Can you post your html too? Also maybe make a good [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example. Currently it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: same answer as @Kalle. However, if what you're doing is "do stuff when a checkbox is manually (un)checked" and you want to "do that same stuff when you (un)check them programmatically", you probably registered to a checkboxes' event like `click` or `focus`. You should trigger this same event on all checkboxes that are not checked (if you want to check them all, or all of them that are checked if you want to uncheck them all).

Comment: I'm editing the page to add more html to my initial post.  Manually unchecking/checking boxes works fine, it does everything I need it to.  However, if the checkbox should be unchecked for any other reason than clicking it (saved cookie), it has no impact on the elements to which its supposed to add the class filtered. meaning i have to click the checkbox each and everytime that I want class="filtered" to be added to the LI's

Comment: essentially i'm thinking of something along the lines of, on load, check if checkbox is checked, if checked, removeClass=filtered, else addClass filtered.  But each listing has its own data attribute (category or source) which is linked to a checkbox.  When I click the checkbox, var dealcat = $(this).data('dealcat'); gets the category from it, I dont know how to check against that value without clicking it.